# Data structure for multi-language dictionary?

Tags: data-structures, dictionary, multilingual

**One-line summary:** suggest optimal (lookup-speed/compactness) data structure(s) for a multi-lingual dictionary representing primarily Indo-European languages (list at bottom).

Say you want to build some data structure(s) to implement a multi-language dictionary for let's say the top-N (N~40) European languages on the internet, ranking choice of language [by number of webpages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Internet_usage) (rough list of languages given at bottom of this question).
The aim is to store the working vocabulary of each language (i.e. 25,000 words for English etc.) Proper nouns excluded. Not sure whether we store plurals, verb conjugations, prefixes etc., or add language-specific rules on how these are formed from noun singulars or verb stems.
Also your choice on how we encode and handle accents, diphthongs and language-specific special characters e.g. maybe where possible we [transliterate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057789/translation-table-for-all-world-languages) things (e.g. [Romanize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanize#Overview_and_summary)  German ß as 'ss', then add a rule to convert it). Obviously if you choose to use 40-100 characters and a trie, there are way too many branches and most of them are empty.

**Task definition:** Whatever data structure(s) you use, you must do both of the following:

1. **The main operation in lookup is to quickly get an indication 'Yes this is a valid word in languages A,B and F but not C,D or E'.** So, if N=40 languages, your structure quickly returns 40 Booleans.
2. **The secondary operation is to return some pointer/object for that word (and all its variants) for each language** (or null if it was invalid). This pointer/object could be user-defined e.g. the Part-of-Speech and dictionary definition/thesaurus similes/list of translations into the other languages/... It could be language-specific or language-independent e.g. a shared definition of *pizza*)

And the **main metric for efficiency is a tradeoff of a) compactness (across all N languages) and b) lookup speed**. Insertion time not important. The compactness constraint excludes memory-wasteful approaches like *"keep a separate hash for each word"* or *"keep a separate for each language, and each word within that language"*.

So:

1. What are the possible data structures, how do they rank on the
   lookup speed/compactness curve?
2. Do you have a unified structure for all N languages, or partition e.g. the Germanic languages into one sub-structure, Slavic into
   another etc? or just N separate structures (which would allow you to
   Huffman-encode )?
3. What representation do you use for characters, accents and language-specific special characters?
4. Ideally, give link to algorithm or code, esp. Python or else C.  -

(I checked SO and there have been related questions but not this exact question. Certainly not looking for a SQL database. One 2000 paper which might be useful: ["Estimation of English and non-English Language Use on the WWW" - Grefenstette & Nioche](http://arxiv.org/ftp/cs/papers/0006/0006032.pdf). And one [list of multi-language dictionaries](http://www.dmoz.org/Reference/Dictionaries/World_Languages/Multilingual/))
Resources: two online multi-language dictionaries are [Interglot (en/ge/nl/fr/sp/se)](http://www.interglot.com/) and [LookWayUp (en<->fr/ge/sp/nl/pt)](http://lookwayup.com/free/).

---

Languages to include:

Probably mainly [Indo-European languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_family) for simplicity: English, French, Spanish, German, Italian, Swedish + Albanian, Czech, Danish, Dutch, Estonian, Finnish, Hungarian, Icelandic, Latvian, Lithuanian, Norwegian, Polish, Portuguese, Romanian, Russian, Serbo Croat, Slovak, Slovenian + Breton, Catalan, Corsican, Esperanto, Gaelic, Welsh

Probably include Russian, Slavic, Turkish, exclude Arabic, Hebrew, Iranian, Indian etc. Maybe include Malay family too. Tell me what's achievable.

Comment: Do you handle localised words? (Localized is the WRONG spelling!)

Comment: I don't know, got any numbers on how they increase the vocabulary size? Are we talking about variants of the same word (e.g. US -ize vs British -ise), or adding entirely new words? I'm only thinking  about a working vocabulary (e.g. 25,000 words in English), not a full lexicon. Let's say: somewhat, up to the point that it doesn't detract from the primary task being constructing a multi-lingual structure for N languages.

Comment: Variations, and is the kind of thing that Mac OS X seems to support by default.

Comment: @Arafangion: Neither localiSed nor localiZed is wrong because they are locali*ed.

Comment: @Alex: whatevs. I'm really interested in quality answers to this question... someone out there must have some suggestion.

Comment: That wasn't an answer to the question, just a mere comment and to someone else. Now, what do you mean by fast? How slow is acceptable? 1 second? 10? 0.01? Will it actually include real definitions or just links to them? How compact should it be compared to the uncompressed content?

Comment: Didn't have hard numbers in mind, but the application I was thinking was being able to identify the language in short context-free messages (such as posts to a bulletin-board/ social media/ chat session/ mailing-list/ search engine), in real-time. So let's say **lookup time must < 10ms, and below that you can optimize for compactness or further speed**. Since the primary purpose was language identification, I don't care if it only contains pointers to definitions.

Comment: @Alex: That was my point, regarding localiSed vs localiZed. :)

Comment: Do you have the data or sample data? I think the best we can do is just try a few approaches and choose the best.

Comment: No. It's just a general question I thought of. I think you're getting hung up on compression within a single language, as opposed to **compactness across languages**. You need to sketch general outlines of how to handle mapping of accents and special characters when constructing the dictionary, to keep the branching factor down. e.g. Do you romanize them? give them a separate letter? establish correspondences between languages? or else what? Do you e.g. partition the N languages into totally separate multilingual subdictionaries (Germanic, Romance, Slavic, Baltic, Turkic, Austronesian ...)?

Comment: It's hard to predict how the whole thing will compress without having that whole thing, especially if there's more than one language and you don't want to separate them in the hope that shared and similar words will help to compress the whole thing better. See, all good compression techniques exploit specific data features, they rely on statistics. Also, a general question like this is close to being considered as "not constructive" or "not a real question" on SO.

Comment: Alex, you're perfectly capable of locating dictionaries for some or all of the N=40 languages I identified (I already gave links to several), doing the compression across languages and telling us an optimal algorithm. The statistics are "words that legally occur in a working vocabulary from all these languages (including noun plurals, verb declensions)". If you want a subset just try the [top-5 European languages by usercounts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_used_on_the_Internet): English, Spanish, Portuguese, German, French.

Comment: It's pretty hard to get a dictionary with all word forms. Most only give you the base form. You can, of course, extract words from a large text corpus, but then it's up to you to find all/most inflected word forms and associate them with base forms. This necessitates you actually learning a bit of grammar and morphology for every language and implementing or finding code to do this work. Btw, Spanish verbs have approximately 100 forms each due to various tenses, 3 persons, 2 counts and the habit of gluing pronouns at the end of some verb forms. About 10% of Spanish verbs are quite irregular.

Comment: Ok, so we maybe want a (multi-language) dictionary which matches possible verb-stems, then tries to match N=40 language-specific conjugation rules. A combination of a dictionary and a grammar, essentially. (Got any links to code for conjugation rules?) Can you address the other parts of the question, namely an efficient mapping of special characters, across languages?

Comment: If your only purpose is to store (and retrieve) the words and descriptions, why not just use plain relational database modelling? There maybe some issues wrt spelling,and homonyms, but that does not look unsolvable. If your purpose also includes classification of unknown text, you could use some "annotated" Markov-chain variant.

Comment: @wildplasser: can you compare the compactness and lookup times of an RDB approach to (say) a Trie? Do you have multiple entries for multiple languages? Do you do (language-specific) stemming?

Comment: No. I don't say you should do the implementation in SQL. I said that you should do the *modelling* like in SQL databases. BTW: I don't think you should do any stemming or spelling error correction or homonym detection. You should accept *any* token and let a middle layer take care of that. ("every problem can be solved by an extra layer of indirection"). For reference: see the original design paper for Google/Pagerank: every token was accepted (or ignored) and the back-end took care of the semantics; there is no special case. The dictionary was designed in such a way that it fit in core .

Comment: @wildplasser: I'm asking for compactness, and I'm only asking you to store a working vocabulary, not accept all tokens. Regardless of modeling in SQL, I only want to know what the final structure looks like, __for that application__? As to Pagerank papers, did you mean [Page, Brin, Motwani, Winograd "The PageRank Citation Ranking: Bringing Order to the Web" (1998)](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/422/1/1999-66.pdf)?

Comment: @wildplasser: Remember we need to store a language-specific definition, not just a language-agnostic wordlist without further information, so I don't see even how Pagerank is applicable.  I don't even see that you could simply accept all tokens, you need to know what language(s) they came from and are legal in, which implies human supervision. If someone submits a misspelling, do you accept it? How do you disambiguate between *mates (verb)* and *mates (noun plural)*?

Comment: No. I meant an older document describing the raw dictionary, the binning and the reversed index part. For the tokeniser, it is easiest to accept *any token*. period. The language-specific stuff (such as stemming, homonyms, language specificity) can be taken care of in a later (N<->M) layer, mapping to a "conceptual" semantic domain. Take for instance the token "loop" which (in English) could mean iteration, or iterate {noun, verb}, or in dutch walk, barrel {verb: stem="lopen", noun : "barrel of a gun"} It is still the same token. To keep the tokeniser simple it should be accepted as-is.

Comment: If someone submits a (popular) misspelling, how does your index automatically learn to distinguish between *heroes (plural of hero)* vs *heros(=sandwiches)*? or in French *héros* ? What about foreign language-users who simply typed in their foreign word without accents, how do we avoid wrongly indexing that?

Comment: @wildplasser: please submit an answer already with your excellent comments! I'm asking about the **final** structure, not the intermediate ones. Hence I think it's irrelevant that *loop* has homonyms across languages at the tokenizing and indexing stage, since we know ultimately a multi-language dictionary needs to separate its Dutch and English meanings. Not asking for the under-the-hood implementation details of how we constructed this.

Comment: That's Ok, I will. But I'm afraid I'll need some SQL to illustrate my point ;-) The Idea about Dutch and English meanings is that you'll have to separate the token from its role and meaning. It's just an extra level of indirection. (In SQL parliance: one or two tables to relate the two domains)

Comment: @wildplasser: Ok but take it that tokenizing is a solved problem and not even the problem of interest here. What you really want to solve is how to learn and separately index the different meanings of [baba](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/baba) across [English](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/baba), [French](http://fr.thefreedictionary.com/baba), [Spanish](http://es.thefreedictionary.com/baba), [Portuguese](http://pt.thefreedictionary.com/baba), [Turkish](http://tr.thefreedictionary.com/baba). When used as a noun its meaning depends on the language: 'rum cake','saliva','father'...

Comment: Strictly I meant to say **interlingual homograph** not homonym.

Comment: The "interlingual momograph" thing is exactly the reason why I hesitated between one and two intermediate layers ("SQL" tables...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will not win points here, but some things.

A multi-language dictionary is a large and time-consuming undertaking. You did not talk in detail about the exact uses for which your dictionary is intended: statistical probably, not translating, not grammatical, .... Different usages require different data to be collected, for instance classifying "went" as passed tense.

First formulate your first requirements in a document, and with a programmed interface prototype. Asking data structures before algorithmic conception I see often for complex business logic. One would then start out wrong, risking [feature creep](http://sixrevisions.com/project-management/eight-tips-on-how-to-manage-feature-creep/). Or premature optimisation, like that romanisation, which might have no advantage, and bar bidrectiveness.

Maybe you can start with some active projects like [Reta Vortaro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/<); its XML might not be efficient, but give you some ideas for organisation. There are several academic **linguistic projects**. The most relevant aspect might be **stemming**: recognising *greet/greets/greeted/greeter/greeting/greetings* (@smci) as belonging to the same (major) entry. You want to take the already programmed stemmers; they often are well-tested and already applied in electronic dictionaries. My advise would be to *research* those projects without losing to much energy, impetus, to them; just enough to collect ideas and see where they might be used.

The data structures one can think up, are IMHO of secondary importance. I would **first collect all in a well defined database**, and then **generate the software used data structures**. You can then compare and measure alternatives. And it might be for a developer the most interesting part, creating a beautiful data structure & algorithm.

---

***An answer***

**Requirement:**

Map of word to list of [language, definition reference].
List of definitions.

Several words can have the same definition, hence the need for a definition reference.
The definition could consist of a language bound definition (grammatical properties, declinations), and/or a language indepedendant definition (description of the notion).

One word can have several definitions (book = (noun) reading material, = (verb) reserve use of location).

**Remarks**

As single words are handled, this does not consider that an occuring text is in general mono-lingual. As a text can be of mixed languages, and I see no special overhead in the O-complexity, that seems irrelevant.

So a over-general abstract data structure would be:

```
Map<String /*Word*/, List<DefinitionEntry>> wordDefinitions;
Map<String /*Language/Locale/""*/, List<Definition>> definitions;

class Definition {
    String content;
}

class DefinitionEntry {
    String language;
    Ref<Definition> definition;
}
```

**The concrete data structure:**

The wordDefinitions are best served with an optimised hash map.

---

***Please let me add:***

I did come up with a concrete data structure at last. I started with the following.

Guava's MultiMap is, what we have here, but [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/)'s collections with primitive types is what one needs, if using a compact binary representation in core.

One would do something like:

```
import gnu.trove.map.*;

/**
 * Map of word to DefinitionEntry.
 * Key: word.
 * Value: offset in byte array wordDefinitionEntries,
 * 0 serves as null, which implies a dummy byte (data version?)
 * in the byte arrary at [0].
 */
TObjectIntMap<String> wordDefinitions = TObjectIntHashMap<String>();
byte[] wordDefinitionEntries = new byte[...]; // Actually read from file.

void walkEntries(String word) {
    int value = wordDefinitions.get(word);
    if (value == 0)
        return;
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
        new ByteArrayInputStream(wordDefinitionEntries));
    in.skipBytes(value);
    int entriesCount = in.readShort();
    for (int entryno = 0; entryno < entriesCount; ++entryno) {
        int language = in.readByte();
        walkDefinition(in, language); // Index to readUTF8 or gzipped bytes.
    }
}
```

Comment: Joop, the challenge is only to 1) quickly identify which language(s) a word is legal in, and 2) return a set of pointer(s) to those definitions. Assume you start with N individual dictionaries, like Reta Vortaro . I have no application in mind, I'm only asking to sketch how this conceptually could be done. Think of it like a Google-style interview question.

Comment: To exploit stemming (*greet/greets/greeted/greeter/greeting/greetings*), the Trie entry for *greet* could have a pointer(s) to a (language-specific) stemmer object (which we lookup with the remaining characters, and returns either NULL or a pointer to a Definition). This simultaneously solves the compactness, lookup. But can we generalize that to a multi-language stemmer...? And how to handle unrelated words with common stem, e.g. *flaming/flamingo/flambé*?

Comment: Actually since *flambé* is a loan-word from French, how could the English stemmer simply point to the French word as being legal in both languages?

Comment: For *flambé* the English stemmer could point to the French word (then you also need either a to have a language-neutral Definition structure, or else DefinitionEntry might contain lists of (language,definition) pairs)? There will be some universal loanwords like *pizza* which are legal in most/all of the N languages. I guess the way you develop that further depends on exactly what a Definition object is (language-specific definition? language-neutral definition? language-specific thesaurus simile list? ...)

Comment: _About stemmers._ Take the Dutch `investering`; an English stemmer would look for `invester` and fail further on.

Comment: Yes that's correct behavior. Here is a [crude Dutch stemmer](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/dutch/stemmer.html). Anyone ever tried multi-language stemmers? (Google shows me some references to e.g. [Xapian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xapian)) Which two languages have greatest similarity for stemming?

Comment: [Snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org/) is a toolkit for foreign-language stemmers. I notice two things about it: a) seems to require romanizing all special characters b) a stemmer can only return a signle result, so no multi-lingual stemmers.

Comment: You can only do stemming **once you know the language**. If you don't know the language (yet) you'll have to (at least) postpone stemming.

Comment: But my entire point is that **you can simultaneously do multilingual stemming AND language classification**. (e.g. [Coveo does](http://www.coveo.com/en/Support/articles/Information%20-%20CES4-060330-3%20-%20Understanding%20Stemming.htm))

Comment: @JoopEggen do you know where I can download a Spanish - English dictionary similar to what they have for Chinese - English (https://cc-cedict.org/wiki/)

Comment: @Growler sorry but at least those are popular languages. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure whether or not this will work for your particular problem, but here's one idea to think about.

A data structure that's often used for fast, compact representations of language is a minimum-state DFA for the language.  You could construct this by creating a trie for the language (which is itself an automaton for recognizing strings in the language), then using of the canonical algorithms for constructing a minimum-state DFA for the language.  This may require an enormous amount of preprocessing time, but once you've constructed the automaton you'll have extremely fast lookup of words.  You would just start at the start state and follow the labeled transitions for each of the letters.  Each state could encode (perhaps) a 40-bit value encoding for each language whether or not the state corresponds to a word in that language.

Because different languages use different alphabets, it might a good idea to separate out each language by alphabet so that you can minimize the size of the transition table for the automaton.  After all, if you have words using the Latin and Cyrillic alphabets, the state transitions for states representing Greek words would probably all be to the dead state on Latin letters, while the transitions for Greek characters for Latin words would also be to the dead state.   Having multiple automata for each of these alphabets thus could eliminate a huge amount of wasted space.

Comment: You didn't say how you handle accents? When you decide whether to 'separate each language by alphabet', one possibility is to map Latin, Greek and Cyrillic equivalent to each other e.g. by [Romanization](http://transliteration.eki.ee/) e.g. [of Greek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Greek). That becomes inefficient where you map one character to two Latin e.g. χ → ch.

Comment: I'm actually not sure what the best way to do this is.  My initially hunch would be to treat basic Latin with accents as separate from Greek and Cyrillic, but I honestly don't know if this is a good idea.  I don't have much experience working with multiple languages, so perhaps this is clearly a poor choice and Romanization is a good idea.

Comment: As for the efficiency, it might not be that much of a hit (though again I'm not sure how bad this would be).  In the worst case I'd assume that this would be a 2x blowup, which is linear in the size of the input.

Comment: Well did you mean use N data structures for N languages? That's larger. Surely it's possible to at least merge the main Romance languages (French, Spanish, Portuguese and maybe Italian)?

Comment: No, you'd definitely want to merge most Romance languages together!  I mainly meant classification by alphabet to avoid having huge wasted space in each table.

Comment: Please tell me roughly how many alphabets that means for the language list I gave? And especially when you merge languages, you'll need to tell me how you handle [diacriticals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic). Spanish and Portuguese use [tilde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde) for different purposes, whereas French doesn't have it at all; how to avoid adding ~20 extra unnecessary characters with accents?

Comment: @templatetypedef let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2482/discussion-between-smci-and-templatetypedef)

Comment: Is this solution an option for a dictionary that is constantly being updated by user input?

Comment: @Suragch To the best of my knowledge there isn't a simple way to use minimum-state automata with updating word lists because minor changes to the word set can have profound changes on the minimum-state automaton. However, I'm hoping to be proven wrong!

Comment: @templatetypedef, That is what I was afraid of but I am trying to check out all of the viable options before starting on such a project.

Answer (score 1):

A common solution to this in the field of NLP is finite automata. See http://www.stanford.edu/~laurik/fsmbook/home.html.

Comment: The link page is not very clear. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

Construct a [minimal, perfect hash function](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) for your data (union of all dictionaries, construct the hash offline), and [enjoy *O(1)* lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Perfect_hash_function) for the rest of eternity.

Takes advantage of the fact your keys are known statically. Doesn't care about your accents and so on (normalize them prior to hashing if you want).

Comment: No, this doesn't address the compactness or overlap between languages. _Man, mankind, manhole, mangiare, Mannschaft..._

Comment: You're not doing the secodary part either: ***you have to also return a pointer to the corresponding definition in each of the N languages***. The challenge was not just to hash a large set of Booleans for N=40 languages, anyone can do that. You want to add efficiency about storing things so you don't need a pointer for every single verb conjugation or noun plural. Consider in English *greet/greets/greeted/greeter/greeting/greetings* should all use the same pointer. Now how to generalize that sort of structure across languages?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar (but not exactly) task: implement a four-way mapping for sets, e.g. `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`

Each item `x` has it's projections in all of the sets, `x.A`, `x.B`, `x.C`, `x.D`;

The task was: for each item encountered, determine which set it belongs to and find its projections in other sets.

Using languages analogy: for any word, identify its language and find all translations to other languages.

**However:** in my case a word can be uniquely identified as belonging to one language only, so no false friends such as burro in Spanish is donkey in English, whereas burro in Italian is butter in English (see also https://www.daytranslations.com/blog/different-meanings/)

I implemented the following solution:

- Four maps/dictionaries matching the entry to its unique id (integer)

  ```
  AtoI[x.A] = BtoI[x.B] = CtoI[x.C] = DtoI[x.D] = i
  ```
- Four maps/dictionaries matching the unique id to the corresponding language

  ```
  ItoA[i] = x.A;
  ItoB[i] = x.B;
  ItoC[i] = x.C;
  ItoD[i] = x.D;
  ```

For each encounter `x`, I need to do 4 searches at worst to get its id (each search is `O(log(N))`); then 3 access operations, each `O(log(N))`. All in all, `O(log(N))`.

I have not implemented this, but I don't see why hash sets cannot be used for either set of dictionaries to make it `O(1)`.

**Going back to your problem:**
Given N concepts in M languages (so N*M words in total)

My approach adapts in the following way:

M lookup hashsets, that give you integer id for every language (or None/null if the word does not exist in the language).
Overlapped case is covered by the fact that lookups for different languages will yield different ids.

For each word, you do M*O(1) lookups in the hash sets corresponding to languages, yielding K<=M ids, identifying the word as belonging to K languages;

for each id you need to do  (M-1)*O(1) lookups in actual dictionaries, mapping K ids to M-1 translations each)

In total, O(M*K*M) which I think is not bad, given your M=40 and K will be much smaller than M in most cases (K=1 for quite a lot of words).

As for storage: N*M words + N*M integers for the id-to-word dictionaries, and the same amount for reverse lookups (word-to-id);

Comment: I don't see the relevance of this to my question, and your premise *"in my case a word can be uniquely identified as belonging to one language only"* is totally artificial and violates the question (so *"unique integer ids across languages"* goes out the window immediately), but anyway, you haven't addressed what single data structure you'd use to handle 'burro' (Spanish), 'burrito' (both Spanish & English), 'burrow' (English), ... "Keep N separate hashes/dictionaries, one for each language" will violate both constraints I gave by being both hugely wasteful on memory, and slower to lookup.

Comment: (added clarification for your case in the body of the post)